# How to remove a set of pixel columns from an image, using GIMP?

Tags: gimp, png, images, dpi

To clarify, say I have an image that is 100px wide and 50px high and I want to make it 50px x 50px, by removing columns from the MIDDLE of the image. i.e. I want to keep the left side of the image, and keep the right side, but remove the middle. I do not want to scale the image in any way. The image is a PNG, with transparent areas.

I'm not very used to GIMP, so be gentle :)

Comment: You could just create a new image the target size, and use GIMP to crop two copies of the original by leaving only the left-most and right-most 25 pixels.  Then, just put them in the new 50x50 image.

Answer (score 1):

I daresay you might be able to automate this with Imagemagick as it has command line options to extract sections of images - see examples here:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_strip

See: Chop, removing rows, columns and edges

Answer (score 1):

This is a good answer over at Stack Overflow if you need a simple, quick way to do this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63279906/609855

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

- Make a 50x50 image (new image, any fill)
- Open your source and select the left 25px area
- Click back to your new image, paste and position to left side
- Go select the right 25 px area, switch and paste, position to right side
- flatten the new image